# Error in changing the directory to google drive even when mounted in google colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

**code**

```
import os
os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/laptop_1.jpg')

%cd '/content/drive/MyDrive/laptop_1.jpg'
```

**error**

```
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/content/drive/MyDrive/laptop_1.jpg'
```

I've tried both the codes on the Colab several times but error remains the same. could anyone suggest for some solution?

Comment: While mounting the drive colab has asked for the authorization

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear: *'/content/drive/MyDrive/laptop_1.jpg'* is no path to a directory, but a file, while `os.chdir()` receives only a directory path. You need to change your code to:

```
import os
os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive')
```

**Note:** If you are in a Google Colab notbook, *MyDrive* is a subdirectory of */content/gdrive*. Furthermore, you need to mount your Google Drive before anything else. In that case:

```
from google.colab import drive
import os

drive.mount('/content/gdrive') # mounting your Google Drive to your Colab notebook
os.chdir('/content/gdrive/MyDrive') # changing the working directory
```